# taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.clientgen.ClientGenTask cannot be found

Tags: ant, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I am getting taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.clientgen.ClientGenTask cannot be found error while trying to build my project.
When googled I found that webserviceclient.jar may be required. But I am not sure in which folder I can get this jar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this task is within the following jar:

```
<weblogic install dir>/server/lib/webservices.jar
```

You can verify with:

```
jar -tf <weblogic install dir>/server/lib/webservices.jar | grep ClientGenTask
```